# Play! Framework 1.2.3 Model is not managed by any plugin

Tags: jpa, playframework, playframework-1.x

I'm using Play! 1.2.3

I'm trying to load data from a yaml file and persist it using JPA, but I am getting an exception

Execution exception
RuntimeException occured : Cannot load fixture rss-sources.yml: Model models.RSSSource is not managed by any plugin

Could someone please offer advice?

The stack trace is

```
Internal Server Error (500) for request GET /

Execution exception (In /app/controllers/Bootstrap.java around line 19)
RuntimeException occured : Cannot load fixture rss-sources.yml: Model models.RSSSource is      not managed by any plugin

play.exceptions.JavaExecutionException: Cannot load fixture rss-sources.yml: Model     models.RSSSource is not managed by any plugin
    at play.jobs.Job.call(Job.java:155)
at Invocation.Job(Play!)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot load fixture rss-sources.yml: Model models.RSSSource is not managed by any plugin
at play.test.Fixtures.loadModels(Fixtures.java:223)
at controllers.Bootstrap.doJob(Bootstrap.java:19)
at play.jobs.Job.doJobWithResult(Job.java:50)
at play.jobs.Job.call(Job.java:146)
... 1 more
Caused by: play.exceptions.UnexpectedException: Model models.RSSSource is not managed by any plugin
at play.db.Model$Manager.factoryFor(Model.java:57)
at play.test.Fixtures.resolveDependencies(Fixtures.java:386)
at play.test.Fixtures.loadModels(Fixtures.java:197)
... 4 more
```

My model class is :

```
package models;

import javax.persistence.*;

import play.db.jpa.*;
import play.data.validation.*;

import org.yaml.snakeyaml.Yaml;

/**
 * Class to describe a news url
 * contains url string and category
 * 
 * 
 *
 */

@Entity
@Table(name="RSSSourcesTable")
public class RSSSource
{
    //variable to old source
    @Required
    @Id
    private String source;

    //variables to hold urls for news category RSS feeds
    private String topNewsURL;
    private String worldNewsURL;
    private String ukNewsURL;
    private String usaNewsURL;
    private String sportsNewsURL;
    private String businessNewsURL;
    private String technologyNewsURL;


    public RSSSource(String source)
    {
        this.source = source;  
    }

    //getters and setters here
}
```

and my bootstrap class is :

```
package controllers;

import play.jobs.Job;
import play.jobs.OnApplicationStart;
import play.jobs.OnApplicationStop;
import play.test.Fixtures;

@OnApplicationStart 
public class Bootstrap extends Job
{
/**
 * On start up this method loads the configuration that is set in the config loader, this contains the connection details for the 
 * RSS feed sources.
 * 
 */
     public void doJob()
    {
        System.out.println("Loading RSS sources from file: rss-sources.yml");
        Fixtures.loadModels("rss-sources.yml");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your model classes should extend `play.db.jpa.Model`, or, in your case, since you are using a custom ID, `play.db.jpa.GenericModel` ([Play JPA documentation](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/1.2.3/jpa)). I.e.

```
public class RSSSource
```

should become

```
public class RSSSource extends GenericModel
```

By the way, you might want to update from Play 1.2.3 to 1.2.5.